# How to display LDIF data in folder tree structure in react js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, ldap, ldif

I have a LDAP's LDIF data and I want to display that LDIF data in react js web app in folder structure format to expand, view its children's and select it.

Any Idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi Did you find any solution for this I am also facing same issue.